# TIKA 1.5 server how to pass additional identifiers like in previous versions?

Tags: apache-tika

We're upgrading from Tika 1.2 to 1.5.

Tika JAX-RPC server used to let you specify additional identifiers as part of the URL
(documented in the tika server README and wiki)

e.g. "protocol://localhost:port/tika/my-identifier-here"

The extra identifier was logged in tika's log - which is immensely helpful in tying the logs together with the callers' logs.

However with Tika 1.5, this no longer works (call result is 404), but the functional call without the extra identifier works just fine.

The docs (and tika wiki) still indicate this is supported - but actual experience says no.

I've been unable to locate any information on this change. Can anyone comment on whether this is an intentional change (docs out of date) or a potential bug, and/or how to pass this information using the 1.5 server API - if it is still possible?

Comment: There has been quite a bit of work on the Tika Server since 1.5, any chance you could retry with a recent nightly build?

Comment: We would prefer to use a release version

Comment: 1.6 is supposed to be being released 2 weeks ago, so it's due shortly! Not sure if that'll fix it, but worth checking, especially as a fix might (just) be able to squeeze into the next release...